# Maven jarsigner plugin

Tags: maven, jarsigner

I just tried to configure the maven jarsigner plugin for signing a jar project.

As far as I can understand, the plugin should run automatically when I run mvn clean package but it doesn't.
I must run mvn clean package jarsigner:sign for the plugin to be executed.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <alias>java-code</alias>
                <keystore>mykeystore.keystore</keystore>
                <keypass>mykeypass</keypass>
                <storepass>mystorepass</storepass>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

I could find the error on my own. The configuration element has to be within the execution element.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, [as the documentation states](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html), the sign goal binds to the package phase. Can you provide any details e.g your pom?

Comment: I just edited the question with additional details.